# Copy value from one column to another (same table) in SQL using a mapping table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to copy the value from one column to another within the same table, and struggling to work out the correct way to do this. 
Ideally I would do this in within the code rather than the SQL, however I am dealing with a legacy application and as such updating the code (whilst a new version is already in development) is a no-no.

I have the following table (`IncomingData`)

```
id PK
SourceID int
QuestionnaireID int
Q1 varchar(500)
Q2 varchar(500)
..
..
Q50 varchar(500)
```

So we would have:

```
id    SourceID    QuestionnaireID    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5
1     5000        10                 1     2     1     5     3
```

Data will occasionally come in(via a webservice) from particular `SourceID`'s where the Q1(etc) needs moving to Q3 in order for it to be processed correctly by our system.
So to this end I have created the following mapping table

```
id    SourceID    QuestionnaireID    SourceQ    DestQ
1     5000        10                 Q1         Q3
1     5000        10                 Q2         Q4
1     5000        10                 Q3         Q5
1     5000        10                 Q4         Q7
1     5000        10                 Q5         Q8
```

My Idea is to create a temporary table matching `IncomingData` copy the values to the correct columns within this temporary table and then update `IncomingData` for that row with the values within the correct column.

Is there an easy way to do this?, the only thing I can see is to create numerous Dynamic SQL statements within this function and execute them. This concerns me because of injection, however the sql to insert into the temp table would only be created from the Mapping Table, so external variables would not be passed to the Dynamic SQL, so would this be an issue?

**Update**

The(my expected) flow of data within this :

1) Data appears within `IncomingData`

2) A stored procedure is scheduled to run that gets the data from `incomingdata`

3) a function is run within the stored procedure that takes `SourceID` and `QuestionnaireID` as parameters and searches `SourceDestXmap` table

4) if there are matches (i.e. some columns need changing), then, for each of the rows within `SourceDestXmap` the value of the `SourceQ` needs inserting into `DestQ` of a temporary table.

so from the example above, the value of IncomingData.Q5 needs to be inserted into tempData.Q8 column where the mappings are worked out from `SourceDestXmap`

*Caveats:*
There could any number of mappings for example QuestionnaireID 11 may have a Q8->Q27 mapping as well as a Q16->Q4 mapping.

**Update #2**

I basically need a more dynamic way of doing something like this:

```
BEGIN
            DECLARE @tmpQ3 varchar(2000) 
            DECLARE @tmpQ4 varchar(2000) 
            DECLARE @tmpQ5 varchar(2000) 
            DECLARE @tmpQ7 varchar(2000) 
            DECLARE @tmpQ8 varchar(2000) 

            SET @tmpQ3 = @prmQ1
            SET @tmpQ4 = @prmQ2
            SET @tmpQ5 = @prmQ3
            SET @tmpQ7 = @prmQ4
            SET @tmpQ8 = @prmQ5

            SET @prmQ1 = NULL
            SET @prmQ2 = NULL
            SET @prmQ3 = NULL
            SET @prmQ4 = NULL
            SET @prmQ5 = NULL

            SET @prmQ3 = @tmpQ3
            SET @prmQ4 = @tmpQ4
            SET @prmQ5 = @tmpQ5
            SET @prmQ7 = @tmpQ7
            SET @prmQ8 = @tmpQ8
        END
```

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand your problem, but can you use triggers to do the update to the other column?

Comment: Well, your table design is - uhm - ehm - uhm - improveable... :-) Do you have a chance to change something there or do you have to stick with that structure?

Comment: @Jeremy I did consider triggers, but ultimately, once Q3 is moved to Q5 then I have lost the value for the original Q5. This is why I'm thinking creating a temporary table and putting the values in there would be good.

Comment: If your problem is not to keep the value you just have overwritten, you might just do this from back to forth? Copy Q5 into Q8, than Q4 into Q7 and so on...

Comment: @Shnugo yes, the table design for `incomingdata` is... interesting... (not my design) but sadly not updatable. the structure of the mapping table is changable though.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the two tables interacts: the source and the destination are swapped, one item from the SourceQ pass to the DestQ, or the full value of SourceQ pass to the DestQ (losing the previous vaue of DestQ and setting SourceQ to NULL)? The data of the mapping table need to be processed in a specific order, in this case how the data need to be ordered?

Comment: @Serpiton I'm thinking that creating a temporary table and inserting the values into the correct columns (from the xmap table) of the temporary table rather than overwriting the existing data. I've updated my question with (hopefully) a more readable flow of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is not exactly what you need (I do not understand it fully - acutally), but you might get an idea, how you can "shift" your values aside and set new values (update) in one single step:

```
DECLARE @IncomingData TABLE(ID INT,SourceID INT,QuestionairID INT,Q1 VARCHAR(10),Q2 VARCHAR(10),Q3 VARCHAR(10),Q4 VARCHAR(10),Q5 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @IncomingData VALUES (1,5000,10,'1','2','3','4','5');

DECLARE @NewData TABLE(ID INT,SourceID INT,QuestionairID INT,Q1 VARCHAR(10),Q2 VARCHAR(10),Q3 VARCHAR(10),Q4 VARCHAR(10),Q5 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @NewData VALUES (1,5000,10,'new1','new2','new3','new4','new5');

--This will shift all original data "two steps aside"...

UPDATE @IncomingData SET id.Q5=id.Q3,id.Q4=id.Q2,id.Q3=id.Q1
                        ,id.Q2=new.Q2
                        ,id.Q1=new.Q1
FROM @IncomingData AS id
CROSS JOIN @NewData AS new

SELECT * FROM @IncomingData
```

The result:

```
ID  SourceID    QuestionairID   Q1      Q2      Q3  Q4  Q5
1   5000        10              new1    new2    1   2   3
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not quite sure this is what i'm after. Could I ask you where the values for `newdata` come from? They -should- be the same values as Incomingdata, just entered into the columns specified in the mapping table. Maybe I need to explain my question a bit better....

Comment: @kolin, OK, for this you might use an UPDATE or INSERT Trigger, maybe even an INSTEAD OF Trigger. within this trigger you can use the pseudo table "inserted" in the place of "newData". Another way would be to define a StoredProcedure to do the insert/update which takes your values as parameters and call it row by row...